# Adding copyright notice to page bottom in full site editing template

Tags: theme-development, full-site-editing

I am adding a function, a copyright notice, to my full site editing theme.

I initially tried a shortcode and added shortcode as a block in the footer within site editor. This renders the notice just inside the opening body tag.

```
function copyright_notice() {
    $year = date("Y"); 
    $site_title = get_bloginfo( 'name' );
    echo '<div>&copy; ' . $year . ' ' . $site_title . ' All rights reserved.</div>';
}
add_shortcode( 'copyright', 'copyright_notice' );
```

I tried a filter and, as expected, the text appears within the scripts before the closing body tag.

```
function copyright_notice() {
    $year = date("Y"); 
    $site_title = get_bloginfo( 'name' );
    echo '<div>&copy; ' . $year . ' ' . $site_title . ' All rights reserved.</div>';
}
add_filter( 'wp_footer', 'copyright_notice' );
```

My questions: Is there a way to add a specific shortcode within a FSE template? Or am I better off creating a custom hook for my filter?